# Is there a way to ensure the label for 0 has no decimal places in plotnine

Tags: python, plotnine

I am producing a bunch of plots using the Plotnine library in Python. Sometimes, when I am using `facet_wrap`, two adjacent plots will have the upper and lower x limits run together. That is, say the upper limit of a plot is 0.001 and the lower limit of the plot is 0.000. These two numbers will bleed together due to the placement of the adjacent plots. One way around this is to change the precision of the x-tick labels, but I'd rather not do that for every single tick. Instead, I was thinking that for the `0` tick, I could have a reduction in precision, because I don't need to specify that this tick is `0.000`; instead it can just be `0`. But I don't know how to do this in Plotnine (or Mizani).

I understand this question does not have any code, but I have provided a screenshot of the behavior I am seeing (see below).[image]